# How to activate UITextView embedded in a navigation bar on view load?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I'm working with Xcode 4.3.3 and iOS 5.1, developing an iPad app.

I have a UITextField as the titleView of a navigation bar (in a Storyboard), hooked up to an outlet like so:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldName;
```

At the end of my implementation of viewDidLoad, I call:

```
[self.textFieldName becomeFirstResponder];
```

And...nothing happens.  I can tap on the UITextField to activate it, but can't seem to have the field active when the view launches.

Background: Upon adding a row in the previous view (a UITableView), I'm segueing to this view and want to enable the text field if what would normally be presented as the title of the view is empty.  That is, upon creating a new row in my database, I want the user's first action to be entering a title.  I'm open to other approaches, but would still like to know how to accomplish the stated question.

**EDIT**

I was able to get it working by calling:

```
 [self.navigationItem.titleView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code there should be working.

I'm guessing there is a simple step you might be missing, like adding the UITextFieldDelegate. I would just suggest going through each step and trying to figure out which isn't working. If that doesn't work, post your Xcodeproj and I (or someone else) can take a closer look.